# Java how to call or notify the calling Class when job is done?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have simple calling to thread which do simple job. when condition is met
i want to invoke or notify the Base Class ( the one that started the thread )
that the job is done .
what is the best way to do this ?

```
class TaskThread implements Runnable 
{

    private int result = -1;
    public TaskThread()
    {

    }    
    //must be thread safe
    public synchronized int getResult()
    {
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        if(result==-1 || result < 0)
        {
            StartFoo();
            result  = InvokeAPI();
            if(result == 1)
            {
            // HERE i like to do something to notify the outside world that the job is done ...  
            }

        }
    }
}


//Base class 
public class ScheduledThreadsManager {

    private static ScheduledThreadsManager instance = null;
    private ScheduledExecutorService scheduler;
    private Runnable pTaskThread = null ;
    protected  ScheduledThreadsManager() 
    {

    }

    //must be set only once in the app life cycle
    public void Init(int corePoolSize,
                       long TimeUnitINSeconds)
    {
            pTaskThread = new TaskThread();
            scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
            scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(pTaskThread,1,TimeUnitINSeconds,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
    public int getResult()
    {
        return pTaskThread.;
    }
    // Runtime initialization
    // By defualt ThreadSafe
    public static ScheduledThreadsManager getInstance() {
        if(instance == null){
            synchronized (ScheduledThreadsManager.class) {
                if(instance == null){
                    instance = new ScheduledThreadsManager();
                }
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }


    public void ShutdownNow()
    {

        pTaskThread = null ;
        scheduler.shutdown();
    }
}
```

now this is how i call it :

```
//somewhere in the code 

ScheduledThreadsManager.getInstance().init(1,10);
int runThis = true;
while(runThis)
{
    int ifOne = ScheduledThreadsManager.getInstance().getResult()
    if(ifOne==1)
    {
        runThis = false;
        ScheduledThreadsManager.getInstance().ShutdownNow()
    }
}
```

im not sure is the best way , can i somehow can method from the TaskThread  run method and update the ScheduledThreadsManager ?

Comment: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077462/learn-java/java-tip-10--implement-callback-routines-in-java.html First hit for "Java Callback" :D

Comment: But you are heavily overcoding this. You could probably do all that you want with an Executor and Futures. See `submit`. Note that Executors' shutdown only makes sure no new Tasks can be added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve it with a interface e.g.

```
interface SomethingToBeCalled{
void notfiy();
}
```

Your BaseClass extends this

```
ScheduledThreadsManager implements SomethingToBeCalled{
void notify() {...};
}
```

And you give your Task Constructor this Interface

```
public TaskThread(SomethingToBeCalled smth)
    {
      this.smth = smth;
    }
```

And you can now notify the BaseClass

```
 if(result == 1)
  {
  smth.notify();
  }
```

Comment: and this BaseClass when notified can update ScheduledThreadsManager  
public method ?

Comment: @user63898 That class name `BaseClass` is actually a substitution for your real class name `ScheduledThreadsManager`. So you can implement it directly into it.

Comment: @user63898 Did you try this?

Comment: Yes! clean and simple Solution long live Java 5!

Answer (score 3):

I think the best approach would be to give a task a callback function:

```
Runnable callback = () -> System.out.println("done!");
```

Then in your task just add `callback.run();` at the end. Or if your task returns a value that you need to consume, use `Consumer` instead of `Runnable`.

Here is a working example:

```
public class Task implements Runnable {

    private final Consumer<String> callback;

    public Task(Consumer<String> callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // do actual work here instead
        String result = new Random().nextInt(2) == 0 ? "a" : "b";

        // call a private method in Caller
        callback.accept(result);
    }

}

public class Caller {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

        executorService.submit(new Task((result) -> print(1, result)));
        executorService.submit(new Task((result) -> print(2, result)));
        executorService.submit(new Task((result) -> print(3, result)));

        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }

    private static void print(int id, String result) {
        System.out.println("task " + id + " done, returned: " + result);
    }

}
```

This allows you to e.g. call private methods of `Caller` and your `Task` will know nothing about it.

Comment: @user63898 I added an example, does it help?

Comment: what is result in the Caller class ? , from when java have "->"  ?

Comment: @user63898 I recommend learning a bit about java 8 and lambdas. A good place to start: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html

Comment: if i don't have to im never going to learn java 8 .... 
man its become so sluggish since oracle Bought them . 
such memory hungry 
i miss java 5 days ...

Answer (score 3):

Don't notify the calling object: use [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) and [`Future`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html).

You can submit a `Runnable` to an `ExecutorService` and get back a `Future`:

```
Future<?> future = executorService.submit(myRunnable);
```

Now you can call `future.get()` (optionally with a timeout), which will block until the Future has completed:

```
future.get();
future.get(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

This means that you don't need to introduce any new callback interfaces, or similar. You also don't need to call `future.get()` immediately: you can submit a whole pile of tasks, and call `get` later.

Note that if you submit a `Callable<T>` to the `ExecutorService`, you get back a `Future<T>`: this is useful if you want your long-running computation to return a value.

Guava extends the `Future` interface with [`ListenableFuture`](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ListenableFutureExplained), which allows you to execute callbacks once the `Future` has completed. Java 8 also adds `CompleteableFuture`, but I'm still in the dark ages, so I've never used that :)

Comment: This is good, however OP may not want to block. If he blocks, there is no reason to use `ExecutorService` at all (assuming no parallelism).

Comment: Besides Guava's `ListenableFuture`, you could use Java 8's `CompletableFuture`.

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak OP spinwaits as far as I could see. So blocking with timeout would be absolutely preferable.

Comment: dont what to block  , and im not using java 8

Comment: @user63898 In which case you need to do something like what JaroslawPawlak suggests - expect using explicit classes rather than lambdas; or use Guava ListenableFutures, which implement callbacks in much the same way. Please add restrictions like that to your question.